# Brute Force the Frog Jumping Game

Tags: java, brute-force

---

The last variation of the Frog Jumping is shown at the end of [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3HDnrehyDM).

> In short, you have **n** number of lily pads in a line and one frog on
>   each one.
>
> In the last variation (the one I want to brute force), the second
>   first and second last lily pads do not have a frog. Your goal is to
>   get all frogs to the same lily pad. Each frog can jump right or left
>   based on the number of frogs on its lily pad, but can't jump on a
>   empty lily pad.
>   
> (pad with 1 frog moves 1 spot, pad with n frogs moves **only** n spots)
>
> Example of a solution for n=12: (there are no solutions below 12)
>
> [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1] - Starting formation of frogs. (counting
>   frogs from 0. to 11.)
>   [1,0,1,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,1] - Frog 3. jumped
>   right 
>  [1,0,1,0,2,1,2,0,1,1,0,1] - Frog 7. jumped left 
>   [1,0,1,0,4,1,0,0,1,1,0,1] - Frogs 6. jumped left 
>   [5,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1] - Frogs 4. jumped left 
>   [0,0,1,0,0,6,0,0,1,1,0,1] - Frogs 0. jumped right
>   [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,7] - Frogs 5. jumped right
>   [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,7] - Frogs 8. jumped right
>   [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9] - Frogs 9. jumped right
>   [0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] - Frogs 11. jumped left- solved

**I want to find solutions for n frogs, if the solution exists.** I know by hand that 12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 have at least one solution and that 1-11 and 13 do not have a solution.

I tried writing a piece of code that would run through all combinations to find a solution for **n** lily pads.

**EDIT:** The code works now, thanks to [OleV.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v), also added logging.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;

// # Brute Force # Brute Force # Brute Force # Brute Force # Brute Force # //
public class Frogger {

    /** 
     * PUBLIC STATIC GLOBAL VARIABLES - Modify these as you wish.
     * 
     * Time Data: Levels < 20 ~ around couple seconds
     *            Level = 20 ~ around a minute
     *            Level = 21 ~ around a quarter of an hour
     *            Level = 22 ~ around a sixth of a minute
     *            Level = 23 ~ around half an hour
     *            Level = 24 ~ around a minute
     * 
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
        public static int Level = 12;
        public static boolean LogSolution = true;
        public static boolean LogAll = false;
    /** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

    // used for logging
    private static Deque<Jump> solution = new ArrayDeque<>(Level);
    private static double time;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // log the time
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // build the world & start jumping
        run(Level);
    }

    public static void run(int n) {

        // create the world
        int[] world = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            world[i] = 1;
        }
        world[1] = 0;
        world[n-2] = 0;

        // start jumping
        if (Level > 11 && Level != 13) jump(world);
        else System.out.println("Unsolvable");
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void jump(int[] world) {

    for (int i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {

        if (world[i] != 0) { // pad has a frog

            // check if it is solved at current pad
            if (world[i] == Level - 2) {
                System.out.println("SOLUTION: " + Arrays.toString(world));
                System.out.println(solution);
                System.out.println("\n" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000 + " seconds");
                System.exit(0);
            }   

            // roll-back var
            int temp = 0;

            // attempts to make a RIGHT jump 

                if (world[i] + i < world.length) { // right jump is in bound
                    if (world[i + world[i]]  != 0) { // can't jump on empty pad

                        temp = world[i];

                        // jump RIGHT
                        world[i + world[i]] += world[i];
                        world[i] = 0;

                        solution.push(new Jump(temp, i, i + temp)); // log the solution step 1/2
                        if (LogSolution) if (LogAll) System.out.println( "J: " + Arrays.toString(world)); // log the jump

                        // continue jumping
                        jump(world); 

                        // roll-back right jump
                        world[i] = temp;
                        world[i + world[i]] -= world[i];

                        if (LogAll) System.out.println("R: " + Arrays.toString(world)); // log the rollback
                        if (LogSolution) solution.pop(); // log the solution step 2/2
                    }
                }   

            // attempts to make a LEFT jump 

                if (i - world[i] >= 0) { // left jump is in bound
                    if (world[i - world[i]]  != 0) { // can't jump on empty pad

                        temp = world[i];

                        // jump LEFT
                        world[i - world[i]] += world[i];
                        world[i] = 0;

                        if (LogSolution) solution.push(new Jump(temp, i, i - temp)); // log the solution step 1/2
                        if (LogAll) System.out.println("J:" + Arrays.toString(world)); // log the jump

                        // continue jumping
                        jump(world); 

                        // roll-back left jump
                        world[i] = temp;
                        world[i - world[i]] -= world[i];

                        if (LogAll) System.out.println("R: " + Arrays.toString(world)); // log the rollback
                        if (LogSolution) solution.pop(); // log the solution step 2/2
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    }

}
```

---

**Side note:** This problem was mathematically solved for all solvable **n** (all n > 11, other than 13, have a solution, reachable by a generalized method). This piece of code is just me attempting to do some recursion in java.

Comment: Without having studied your code closely, I believe you can save some time by not copying the array each time and instead just undoing your jump when backtracking.

Comment: The better approach would be to think about it mathematically instead of brute forcing.

Comment: It seems to me your solution is more complicated than needed. Your `jump` method is 70 lines; I can write one in less than 40. It solves level 20 in a little over a minute. I don’t mind giving you my code, but isn’t it more fun to write your own?

Comment: My `jump` method does not have an `s` parameter (in fact I didn’t really understand what `s` is in yours). Rather it loops over all pads and sees if a left and/or a right jump can be done from the pad in question. I think this saves some calls compared to your solution (just solved level 21, took between 10 and 30 minutes).

Comment: I agree that it is not clear what the code does. Can you provide more explanation to the logic/steps performed?
Please try to give more clear names to variables. What means s variable. If it is the length of jump, then why there is check "if (s < w.length*2 - 1) {"?
Is it possible that there will be jump for more then length of array?

Comment: @OleV.V. I updated the code: I tried doing something like you mentioned, but the rollback produces negative values & I'm not sure if I'm looping trough all the combinations. Can you post your code as an answer so I can study it?

Comment: I will when I get home to it in the evening.

Comment: At a glance: in your edited code, the right jump looks right, but it seems you are not yet rolling back the left jump when backtracking.

Comment: Your negative number probably comes from rolling back a right jump on top of a non-rolled-back left jump so the frog/s you are trying to put back, are no longer where they were right after the right jump (hard to explain clearly).

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed, seems to be working now. I'll wait till you post yours so I can study it and accept it as an answer to close this matter.

Comment: @OleV.V. Is there way to log the solution steps, without affecting the performance much?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136755/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-dushdushdush).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got it to work. I don’t think you need my code now, but I will give at the bottom of this answer in case.

First, how does one log a solution? I guess you’re thinking that knowing that the end result was `[0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` is not that interesting; we’d like to know how it was obtained. I will present two ways.

The easier way is store each step as it is tried and then delete it when backtracking. Then when you get to the solution, you have also stored the steps that lead to it. Use a stack or similar:

```
private static Deque<Jump> solution = new ArrayDeque<>(Level);
```

(`java.util.ArrayDeque` is the recommended class for both stacks and queues; for a stack `ArrayList` is another option.) Now in your code, where it says `log the jump` do

```
                    solution.push(new Jump(temp, i, i + temp));
```

At `log the rollback` do

```
                    solution.pop();
```

Use a simple auxiliary class `Jump` that could for instance look like this:

```
public class Jump {
    int count;
    int from;
    int to;

    public Jump(int count, int from, int to) {
        this.count = count;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + count + " frog/s jump from " + from + " to " + to;
    }
}
```

When I tried it in my solution, one search took 20 % longer. I’d say it’s acceptable. If you are very concerned about performance, only log on your way out from having found the solution. This will require you to return a boolean to indicate success rather than using System.exit() for stopping the search. Now your recursive call becomes:

```
                    if (jump(world)) {
                        solution.push(new Jump(temp, i, i + temp));
                        return true;
                    }
```

You get the elements in your solution stack in the opposite order than before, I expect you to figure that out. Also instead of `System.exit(0);` do `return true;`. At the bottom of the method, return false. I have not measured performance impact, but I expect it to be minute compared to logging nothing. Now you can get output like:

```
1 frog/s jump from 3 to 4
1 frog/s jump from 7 to 6
2 frog/s jump from 6 to 4
4 frog/s jump from 4 to 0
5 frog/s jump from 0 to 5
6 frog/s jump from 5 to 11
1 frog/s jump from 8 to 9
2 frog/s jump from 9 to 11
9 frog/s jump from 11 to 2
```

Finally here’s how I did, just for the sake of completeness. I haven’t spotted any interesting differences from your code.

```
public static void jump(int[] world) {
    for (int fromIndex = 0; fromIndex < world.length; fromIndex++) { // index of pad to jump from
        // any frog/s here?
        int frogsJumping = world[fromIndex];
        if (frogsJumping > 0) {
            // try to jump left; frogsJumping frogs jump frogsJumping places
            int targetIndex = fromIndex - frogsJumping;
            if (targetIndex >= 0 && world[targetIndex] > 0) { // must not jump to empty pad
                performJump(fromIndex, targetIndex, world, frogsJumping);
            }
            // try a right jump
            targetIndex = fromIndex + frogsJumping;
            if (targetIndex < world.length && world[targetIndex] > 0) {
                performJump(fromIndex, targetIndex, world, frogsJumping);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void performJump(int fromIndex, int toIndex, int[] world, int frogsJumping) {
    solution.push(new Jump(frogsJumping, fromIndex, toIndex));
    world[fromIndex] = 0;
    world[toIndex] += frogsJumping;
    if (world[toIndex] == noOfFrogs) {
        System.out.println("Solved: " + Arrays.toString(world));
        System.exit(0);
    }
    jump(world);
    // backtrack
    world[toIndex] -= frogsJumping;
    world[fromIndex] = frogsJumping;
    solution.pop();
}
```